# Changing the value of a line with n lines (jquery, php, mysql)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

When I click on "lock" I want only the line where I clicked to change the status to true and the lock be locked. When I click on "unlock" I want only the line where I clicked to change the status to false and the released lock.

**In my current code:**

1. when I click on a lock on the first line your status changes and also the lock, but the lock of the other lines also change. I need help to fix this.
2. There is also another thing that I think I should use ajax. When the table is generated and executed for the first time all status will be in false and the lock "open" To mark a line as locked (lock) the status will make is true, and I need to send this "true" pro database and save it through a php script, so that, to reload the page status I had changed continues saved.

I am using the following plugin Context menu:
For better visualization, I put my code in pastebin.

**change.js**

```
$(function(){
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one',

    items: {
      "block": {
        name: "Lock",
        icon: "edit",
        callback: function(key, options){
          var m = $(this).text();
          var set = block(m, $(this)); // passando  - this - como parâmetro de função


        }
      },
      "sep1": "----------",
      "unblock": {
        name: "Unlock",
        icon: "cut",
        callback: function(key, options){
          var m = $(this).text();
          var set = unblock(m, $(this)); // passando  - this - como parâmetro de função

        }
      }
    }
  });
});

function block(x, thisObj)
{
  if (x === "false")
    x = "true";

    thisObj.html(x);
    $(".lock1").html('<i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}

function unblock(x, thisObj)
{
  if (x === "true")
    x = "false";

    thisObj.html(x);
    $(".lock1").html('<i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>');

}
```

[PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/5GkJBQKq).

**network.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb2");
?>

<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Ir para</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">dashboard</a></li>

</ul>



<div class="page-content-wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="page-title">
              <h2><span class="fa fa-hand-spock-o"></span> - Virtual Private Network</h2>
              <p id="test">abc</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table datatable table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Common Name</th>
                  <th>Real Address</th>
                  <th>Virtual Address</th>
                  <th>Bytes Sent</th>
                  <th>Bytes Received</th>
                  <th>Since</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Blocked</th> <!--inserir a imagem de cliente bloqueado ou não -->
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">orion</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">177.43.212.110</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">172.16.191.145</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">872199</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">860412</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">Wed May 25 07:22:52 2016</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">false</td>
                  <td class="lock1"><i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">elgin</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">189.10.58.244</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">172.16.6.210</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">301365</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">250459</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">Wed May 25 07:01:37 2016</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">false</td>
                  <td class="lock1"><i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">databits</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">187.17.235.203</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">172.16.136.217</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">459833</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">409771</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">Wed May 25 06:09:01 2016</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">false</td>
                  <td class="lock1"><i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">proficio</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">179.213.177.117</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">172.16.196.93</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">1083595</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">945154</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">Tue May 24 21:36:21 2016</td>
                  <td class="context-menu-one">false</td>
                  <td class="lock1"><i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
?>
```

[PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/bJgKAWwU).

My table:
[image]

The "lock" option:
[image]

Comment: jquery: http://pastebin.com/5GkJBQKq

php: http://pastebin.com/bJgKAWwU

Comment: We need to see the relevant code **here** (not as a link).  And we don't need to see all of your code, just the part that's related to your question.

Comment: What I put on pastebin is exactly the relevant parts

Comment: I made an edit to the question... It is in pending review. Hold on! ;)

Comment: I looked at it... And I think the problem is on this line (in both block() and unblock() functions) : `$(".lock1").html('<i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>');` **Here**, the selector you use targets ALL your padlocks icons. You have to find a way to target only the right one. Sadly... I don't know how you could pass something like a line ID  to your `$.contextMenu({` function... But I think this is the track to investigate.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thanks! 
But how can I get the id of the column of the row where I clicked?

Comment: This what I say : don't know yet... But trying. Here, I reproduced your code in a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vf8gdmpL/1/

Comment: Got it!... Hold on I'll edit my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a fun one!

First, I changed the position of `context-menu-one` class for the parent's.
And delegated the action on it's `td`s by this: `selector: '.context-menu-one td'`.
Because it makes less elements to "watch" for jQuery... And cleans the code.

Then... I modified the callback functions in your `items` object.
I played with `.parent()`, `siblings()` and `prev()` to target all the right elements.

HTML:

```
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Ir para</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">dashboard</a></li>

</ul>



<div class="page-content-wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <div class="page-title">
              <h2><span class="fa fa-hand-spock-o"></span> - Virtual Private Network</h2>
              <p id="test">abc</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table datatable table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Common Name</th>
                  <th>Real Address</th>
                  <th>Virtual Address</th>
                  <th>Bytes Sent</th>
                  <th>Bytes Received</th>
                  <th>Since</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Blocked</th> <!--inserir a imagem de cliente bloqueado ou não -->
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr class="context-menu-one row">
                  <td>orion</td>
                  <td>177.43.212.110</td>
                  <td>172.16.191.145</td>
                  <td>872199</td>
                  <td>860412</td>
                  <td>Wed May 25 07:22:52 2016</td>
                  <td>false</td>
                  <td class="lock1"><i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="context-menu-one row">
                  <td>elgin</td>
                  <td>189.10.58.244</td>
                  <td>172.16.6.210</td>
                  <td>301365</td>
                  <td>250459</td>
                  <td>Wed May 25 07:01:37 2016</td>
                  <td>false</td>
                  <td class="lock1"><i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="context-menu-one row">
                  <td>databits</td>
                  <td>187.17.235.203</td>
                  <td>172.16.136.217</td>
                  <td>459833</td>
                  <td>409771</td>
                  <td>Wed May 25 06:09:01 2016</td>
                  <td>false</td>
                  <td class="lock1"><i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="context-menu-one row">
                  <td>proficio</td>
                  <td>179.213.177.117</td>
                  <td>172.16.196.93</td>
                  <td>1083595</td>
                  <td>945154</td>
                  <td>Tue May 24 21:36:21 2016</td>
                  <td>false</td>
                  <td class="lock1"><i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
  $.contextMenu({
    selector: '.context-menu-one td',

    items: {
      "block": {
        name: "Lock",
        icon: "edit",
        callback: function(key, options){
        console.log("HERE");
          if ($(this).parent().hasClass("row")){
          console.log("HERE IF");
            thisRowPadlock = $(this).siblings(".lock1");

            var m = $(this).siblings(".lock1").prev().text();
            console.log(m);
            var set = block(m, thisRowPadlock, $(this).siblings(".lock1").prev()); // passando  - this - como parâmetro de função
          }
        }
      },
      "sep1": "----------",
      "unblock": {
        name: "Unlock",
        icon: "cut",
        callback: function(key, options){
          console.log("THERE");
          if ($(this).parent().hasClass("row")){
            thisRowPadlock = $(this).siblings("lock1");

            var m = $(this).siblings(".lock1").prev().text();
            console.log(m);
            var set = unblock(m, thisRowPadlock, $(this).siblings(".lock1").prev()); // passando  - this - como parâmetro de função
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
});

function block(x, padlock, thisObj)
{
console.log("Function block");
  if (x === "false")
    x = "true";

    thisObj.html(x);
    $(padlock).html('<i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
}

function unblock(x, padlock, thisObj)
{
console.log("Function unblock");
if (x === "true")
    x = "false";

    thisObj.html(x);
    $(padlock).html('<i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>');

}
```

And a [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/cdq1Lzum/) (with some missing CSS, sorry).

Comment: I am trying to use your code but the padlock don't change D-:... And the table became a bit "buggy"

Comment: Did you change all 3 functions **AND** the HTML (Wich I think is produced by your PHP) ?

Comment: I used the jQuery's ContextMenu `CDN`s for it... Version 2.2.0 [(REF)](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-contextmenu) **and** jQuery 1.12.4 [(REF)](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/1.12.4)

Comment: Yes! In your Fiddle, more precisely in line of the block function, i changed `$(padlock).html('<i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i>');` to `$(padlock).text("1")` and unblock to `$(padlock).text("0")`.

If I change the status, the padlock "number" is changed, but if i change the status the second time, padlock "number" don't change

Comment: Well, maybe. I wasn't seeing the famous padlock because of the missing CSS... So if you do the same on the unblock() fct. Does it all work ?

Comment: As is missing css padlock (and unnecessary I put here) we will do so: locked padlock is "1" and unlocked is "2".

Comment: You know you can update the Fiddle with the missing CSS and this change? It would be usefull for future readers. Post the updated Fiddl link when done ;)

Comment: For future readers, the **"working Fiddle"** as been updated... And **really is working now**. Thanks to @Cesar A. Fonseca's patience !